# Haskell - Printing Multiple Non-String Variables

Tags: python, haskell, output

I am writing a program that reads two integers from the command line, doubles them, and then prints them back out. So my program reads in the Args, casts them to Ints, and then doubles them. My question is about outputting: in Python, I could just write:

`>>>a = 9`
`>>>b = 10`
`>>>print a,b`
`9 10`

which gives me satisfactory output. In Haskell, there is a similar `print` statement to print a given variable - e.g.

`Prelude> let a = 10`
`Prelude> print a`
`10`

I am wondering if there is a Haskell equivalent to python `print a,b`, so I can print multiple variables at once. Otherwise, I've had to do is convert the doubled Ints back to strings, and then write:
`putStrLn (doubledint1 ++ " " ++ doubledint2)`

Is there a way to print multiple variables that is more effective than the laborious method of manually converting to strings, and then calling putStrLn on their concatenation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `mapM_`, either over `print` or `putStr.show`:

```
Prelude> mapM_ print [a, b]
9
10

mapM_ (putStr . show) [a, b]
910Prelude>
```

*See [input-output section of learn you a haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output).*

You could get the spaces and new line:

```
Prelude> let pylike_print ints = mapM_ (\x -> putStr $ (show x) ++ " ") ints >> putStr "\n"
Prelude> pylike_print [9, 10]
9 10
```

Comment: I have two different types, `Book` and `Creator`.  How do I print out `warAndPeace` which is a `Book` and `leoTolstoy` who is a `Creator`?  I tried `mapM_ print (warAndPeace, leoTolstoy)` in `main::IO()` but it only prints `leoTolstoy`

Answer (score 2):

You can convert each int in your list to a string using `show` and create the joined string using `intercalate`:

```
import Data.List

let ints = [9, 10]
print $ intercalate " " (map show ints)
```

As @raymonad points out in the comments, you should use `putStrLn` instead of `print` if you don't want the output string to be quoted.

Comment: Then you probably want `putStrLn` (with `print` you get a quoted string).

Comment: What do I need to import to use intercalate?

Comment: Instead of `intercalate " "` you can also use `unwords`, which is in the Prelude.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use `printf`: (from `Text.Printf`)

```
printf "%d %d" a b
```

Comment: This has the advantage of working if a and b are different types.